# One SQL Server stored procedure to retrieve one item or multiple using table valued parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

How do I add a conditional to a single stored procedure to either return one item or to join a tvp to return many items?

So I want to be able to do

```
Select *
From table
where id = @id
```

or

```
Select t.*
From table t
join tvp tvp on t.id = tvp.id
```

Would it be terrible to pass in a tvp for just one item every time so I can avoid the first query? Am I being lazy and should this just be two different stored procedures?

Comment: What is the issue with passing a tvp with a single row?

Comment: @SeanLange that's why I asked. Isn't there a performance hit using a tvp if it's only getting one row? In my app the single row retrieval happens a lot more than the bulk load.

Comment: You could take my word for it but...wouldn't it be simpler, quicker and better to try it out and check out the performance difference on your system?

Comment: @SeanLange not when I gotta get it done before COB today!!!

Comment: LOL so you would rather take a chance that somebody on the internet gives you solid advice instead of testing it yourself? At this point it has been 23 minutes since you posted your question. You could have written a quick test and discovered the answer in less than 10. Not trying to be unhelpful here but the best performance answers come from testing on the system it will be running on.

Comment: I would go with the tvp, any performance difference is likely to be so insignificant for creating a single row tvp instead of a scalar variable it is probably not even measurable.

Comment: You have to have two different queries, and I would suggest two different stored procedures.  The result sets have different columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suspect in their haste to post this as quickly as possible they don't really need different result sets. Just used select * to save time. But you are absolutely right, as posted those two queries don't return the same columns. :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff  The result set is the same, I've updated the question because of your attention to detail.

Comment: @SeanLange There was no time to profile because I had to run out to get a scone.  I'm going to use two stored procs because that feels like the right thing to do. It feels like the right thing because it's the more annoying thing to do. I just need to figure out how to avoid the duplication of code in the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before with two procedures: the first procedure takes the TVP, the other procedure takes a single ID, packages it as a TVP and calls the first procedure. I did it for backwards compatibility purposes, but it's applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Select t.*
From table t
where id = @id or
      (@id is null and t.id in (select tvp.id from tvp));
```

Comment: Just don't forget to add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the query

Comment: I'd rather use a join, that list of ID's can get real big

Comment: @user3093582 . . . A `join` and `in` should have pretty much the same performance in this case.